# Is there a replacement for setZipClass in PhpSpreadsheet?

Tags: php, phpexcel, phpspreadsheet

I'm migrating my app from PhpExcel to PhpSpreadsheet.  Is there a replacement for setZipClass?  I can't find it in the documentation.  Below is the line that I'm trying to update.

```
PHPExcel_Settings::setZipClass(PHPExcel_Settings::ZIPARCHIVE);
```

Comment: with a quick search for `zip` in the docs I would say no: https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/develop/topics/migration-from-PHPExcel/#pclzip-and-ziparchive

Answer (score 0):

This is from *phpspreadsheet* :

> Support for PclZip were dropped in favor of the more complete and modern PHP extension ZipArchive . So the following were removed: **PclZip PHPExcel_Settings::setZipClass()** **PHPExcel_Settings::getZip**

[phpspreadsheet documentation](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/search.html?q=zip)